# How to set up Google+ Sign-In for server-side apps for a website?

Tags: php, google-plus

I am trying to add a **sign in with google+** button on my website just to retrieve basic information.
but the documentation doesnt seem to make any sense to me. 
(https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)
it appears out of date and not complete and there seems to be various api library's that can be used.

Can anyone explain all this more clearly or tell me how i should go about making this work and which api library to use etc?
a full sample with code would be very helpful.

thanx

Ok so i will add more detail. google development page gives this as an example for a login button :

```
<html>

<head>

  <!-- BEGIN Pre-requisites -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer>
  </script>
  <!-- END Pre-requisites -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="signinButton">
  <span class="g-signin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    data-clientid="your-client-id"
    data-redirecturi="postmessage"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-callback="signInCallback">
  </span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
function signInCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['code']) {

    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
    $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');

    // Send the code to the server
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'plus.php?storeToken',
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(result) {
        // Handle or verify the server response if necessary.

        // Prints the list of people that the user has allowed the app to know
        // to the console.
        console.log(result);
        if (result['profile'] && result['people']){
          $('#results').html('Hello ' + result['profile']['displayName'] + '. You successfully made a server side call to people.get and people.list');
        } else {
          $('#results').html('Failed to make a server-side call. Check your configuration and console.');
        }
      },
      processData: false,
      data: authResult['code']
    });
  } else if (authResult['error']) {
    // There was an error.
    // Possible error codes:
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatially log in the user
    // console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but it also provides:

```
<?php 
// Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
  // Store it in the session for later validation.
  $state = md5(rand());
  $app['session']->set('state', $state);
  // Set the client ID, token state, and application name in the HTML while
  // serving it.
  return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
      'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
      'STATE' => $state,
      'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
  ));
   // Ensure that this is no request forgery going on, and that the user
  // sending us this connect request is the user that was supposed to.
  if ($request->get('state') != ($app['session']->get('state'))) {
    return new Response('Invalid state parameter', 401);
  }
  $code = $request->getContent();
  $gPlusId = $request->get['gplus_id'];
  // Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.
  $client->authenticate($code);

  $token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
  // Verify the token
  $reqUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' .
          $token->access_token;
  $req = new Google_HttpRequest($reqUrl);

  $tokenInfo = json_decode(
      $client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());

  // If there was an error in the token info, abort.
  if ($tokenInfo->error) {
    return new Response($tokenInfo->error, 500);
  }
  // Make sure the token we got is for the intended user.
  if ($tokenInfo->userid != $gPlusId) {
    return new Response(
        "Token's user ID doesn't match given user ID", 401);
  }
  // Make sure the token we got is for our app.
  if ($tokenInfo->audience != CLIENT_ID) {
    return new Response(
        "Token's client ID does not match app's.", 401);
  }

  // Store the token in the session for later use.
  $app['session']->set('token', json_encode($token));
  $response = 'Succesfully connected with token: ' . print_r($token, true);

?>
```

But it doesnt say where to put that last bit of code or how to refer to an api library or where to put the secret or anything. so i could do with some pointing in the righ direction please?

Comment: anyone know why i've been given a -1 for this? seems like a valid question to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so if anyone else is having trouble.
[i followed the tutorial on this link](http://www.gvngroup.be/doc/Google/google_plus_sign_in_tutorial.php)

I downloaded the api library from there, changed the configs file and used the example that is provided and it worked fine.

to make it work on a localhost you have to set your  **Authorized JavaScript origins** to a localhost:# for example `http://localhost:12345`

then to make your browser accept the folder or the signin page in command prompt type in

`cd c:/the/path/of/the/downloaded/api/example`

then type in:

```
php -S localhost:12345
```

hope that helps anyone

Comment: the link is broken